# Fill in zeros for missing records after aggregation in Oracle

Tags: oracle

This is a minimal example of the problem I am facing. Imagine we have a table `RAIN` with columns `RAINFALL`, `LOCATION` and `DATETIME` which indicates the mm of rainfall in each city, recording also the date.

```
RAINFALL || LOCATION || DATETIME 
13       || Paris    || 5 Jan 2016
10       || London   || 5 Jan 2016
5        || New York || 5 Jan 2016
7        || Paris    || 13 Jan 2016
24       || London   || 13 Jan 2016
4        || Paris    || 21 Jan 2016
```

I want to aggregate the mm of rain per city per week, so what I can do is the following:

```
SELECT  sum(RAINFALL) as RAINFALL,
        to_char(DATETIME,'IW')  as  week_number,
        LOCATION 
FROM  RAIN
group by to_char(DATETIME,'IW') , LOCATION;
```

This will output something like:

```
10  01  London
5   01  New York
13  01  Paris
24  02  London
7   02  Paris
4   03  Paris
```

at least for my settings. What I would really like it to output though is:

```
10  01  London
5   01  New York
13  01  Paris
24  02  London
0   02  New York
7   02  Paris
4   03  Paris
0   03  New York
0   03  London
```

The difference is that I want the query to fill the 0s where no record exists for each week where even just one city does have a record. I do not want weeks, for which no record exists. How can I do this in Oracle?

I understand that summing the rainfall is of little value in this example as we just have on value per week per city, but I created this minimal example in the hope of making my question clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Partition Outer Join http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=312 .
This feature is available from Oracle 10g onwards.

The following query will select all the distinct weeks from the table and will partition outer join with the same table.

```
WITH b
        AS (SELECT DISTINCT TO_CHAR (DATETIME, 'IW') AS week_number
              FROM tmp_r)
  SELECT NVL (SUM (RAINFALL), 0) AS RAINFALL, b.week_number, LOCATION
    FROM b
         LEFT OUTER JOIN tmp_r a
            PARTITION BY (location)
            ON (b.week_number = TO_CHAR (a.DATETIME, 'IW'))
GROUP BY b.week_number, LOCATION
ORDER BY b.week_number, location;
```

The above query will give the output which you are looking for.

Comment: thank you, this does the trick! you might want to type RAIN instead of tmp_r, but the rest seems to work just fine!